# Rate of growth of linear and logarithmic functions

Tags: limits

I have the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}=2$$

I know for sure that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log{x}}{x}=0$$

Because $x$ grows a lot faster than $\log{x}$. Then why wouldn't the first limit be equal to $0$ as well?

Comment: Think about what happens if you make the numerator SMALLER by omitting the $+ x$ part. If the limit exists when you do this (and it will exist, in fact), then the limit you will get has to be less than or equal to the limit you have. So if omitting the $+x$ term gives you a positive limit (and it does, in fact), then you can't have a zero limit when the $+x$ term is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it has that $e^{2x+1}$ in the numerator it is making all the difference

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}\right)}{x}\le\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\left({{2x+1}}\right)}{x}\le\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}$$
$$2\le\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}$$

find the limit using Lhopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{2x+1 }\cdot 2+1}{e^{2x+1} +x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log\left({e^{2x+1}}+x\right)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2+\frac{1}{e^{2x+1}}}{1+\frac{x}{e^{2x+1}}}=2 $$

Comment: All you have shown is that the limit has a lower bound of $2$.

Comment: but it proves that the limit it not equal to 0

Comment: we can easily find the limit using the Lhopital's rule

Comment: Sure, but you need not resort to LHR when there are much more elementary approaches available.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show that limit is indeed 2

Comment: The middle expression of the last line is incorrect; it's missing a limit.